# Запретить менять последнее число в input

Tags: javascript, jquery

При вводе номера карты и кода в поля `input` последнее число всегда заменяется если продолжить ввод. Как это отменить?

Возможно где-то здесь:

```
function checkMaxInput(){
var max = $(this).data('max');
var keyCode = event.keyCode;
if(
    keyCode!=key_code_map.backspace &&
    keyCode!=key_code_map.delete &&
    keyCode!=key_code_map.go &&
    keyCode!=key_code_map.next &&
    this.value.length==max
    ) {
    this.value = this.value.slice(0,-1)
}
   };
```

[Полный код](http://jsfiddle.net/lilubanana/vkfarha6/12/)

**UPD**

Необходимо чтобы при вводе максимального числа, ввод прекращался, и замена последнего числа не происходила. Т.е. необходимо сделать так: когда введена последняя максимальная цифра в input, при дальнейшем наборе чисел ввод не происходит.

Answer (score 1):

```
this.value = this.value.slice(0,-1)
```

Вот эта строка обрезает значение инпута на один символ с конца.

В данном случае идет проверка на максимальное количество символов в инпуте + проверятся какие клавиши нажаты ( обработка `backspace-a`, `delete-а` )

Попробуйте закомментировать эту строку, посмотрите что будет, либо опишите, какое именно поведение вам нужно при превышении максимальной длины значения инпута

Comment: необходимо чтобы при вводе максимального числа, ввод прекращался, и замена последнего числа не происходила. т.е. когда введена последняя максимальная цифра в `input`, при дальнейшем наборе чисел ввод не происходит.

Comment: по поводу `this.value = this.value.slice(0,-1)` это комментировать нельзя. точно не могу объяснить, но этот код нужен чтобы редактирование происходило корректно, без него каретка переходит в начало или в середину строки